# Having an object follow the graph of a Parametric Function with THREE.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

In THREE.js I have created a webpage that graphs parametric equations for viewing with a VR headset, and I'm trying to determine a way to create an interesting demo for it. My goal is to create a sort of rollercoaster ride, where the camera follows along the function.

The parametric equation function in my code returns Vector3's that create the graph, so I assume this would be a good place to get positions for the rollercoaster. However, I am unfamiliar with animation. How can I make my camera, or any object for that matter, follow these vectors?

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/qGPTT/133/

Comment: I believe that is similar.  I have looked at that fiddle before.  The difference is that I can't create the analogous vectors as the spline using the THREE.ParametricGeometry function.  I will try to access the source code for that function.  I'll let you know how it goes, thanks for your help.